# std::unique_ptr and exception safety

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Do I need to wrap `std::unique_ptr` usage with `try/catch` in code which should be exception safe?
`std::unique_ptr` will hold a raw memory block created by `::malloc` (with my custom deleter to call `::free`).

Comment: `malloc`and `free` are c functions. They cannot throw. So what kind of exception do you want to `catch`?

Comment: No exceptions are generated by `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. All of `std::unique_ptr`'s [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr#Exceptions)* are `noexcept`
2. `malloc` won't throw any exception on failure... it will just return `nullptr`.
3. I believe your deleter's constructors won't throw anything either.

So you don't need to catch anything, since nothing will be thrown.

---

*: See C++11 §20.7.1.2.1 `unique_ptr` constructors [unique.ptr.single.ctor]

Answer (score 9):

**As mentioned in the comments, this answer is relevant for C++14 only**.

Despite the good answer from @keenyt, it's worth to say that `std::make_unique<T>` can throw, even though the constructors of `std::unique_ptr` are `noexcept`.
Actually, whether the above mentioned statement throws or not mostly depends on the constructors of the type `T` involved.

As an example from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) for `std::make_unique`:

> May throw std::bad_alloc or any exception thrown by the constructor of T. If an exception is thrown, this function has no effect.

So, a refinement of the answer would be: no, you don't need a `try/catch` block, unless you are using `std::make_unique` and the constructors of your type `T` can throw.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But `std::make_unique` was introduced in c++14. But my question was about c++11.

Comment: @denys Oh, sorry, I didn't see the tag. I'm removing the answer if you prefer.

Comment: I think it helpful anyway. Just mention that it is related to c++14.

Comment: Keep your answer, I actually came looking for exactly what you answered here but started up looking for unique_ptr exceptions first. You answered my question even though it was different to the OP. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is really important